# Django rest framework foreign key is null

Tags: django

I am a newbie in Django, and I had implemented an many to many relationship, however one field which is is null.

When I post `profile` it is null. Below is how I add it:

```
    "profile": {
            "id": 1,
            "profile_pic": "/media/images/default.jpg",
            "story": null,
            "user": 1,
            "post": []
        }
```

Then, below is my **models** file  :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey('Profile', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='profile', null=True, blank=True)
```

Then, my **serializers** file :

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        depth = 1
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then finally my **views** file :

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_user(request):

    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response()
```

What I want is to post all the data and comes back in response.

Also I am using react axios with ```multipart/form-data``  but my main goal for now is just be able to add it with rest framework and I don't care if it applcation/json or something other.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your view to:

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_user(request):

    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise=True)
    serializer.save()

    return Response()
```

This will raise a `ValidationError` if the data isn't right, whereas previously would fail quietly. It may help you debug further.